# In css select first child *of each line* with wrapped flexboxes (first-column?)

Tags: css, flexbox, margins

I have a flexbox that is basically a "list of sub divs". The box' main feature is the automated wrapping. However I notice that, due to children's wrapping value, there is also an offset to the left of the box.

I wish to remove this. I've tried doing this by giving the container a negative padding: however that seems to be disallowed.

Then I tried to find a selector for the "first child on each line", but that also failed. Is there a way to do this in css?

Alternatively, an a grid `display: grid` be made to have variable width columns, and automatically calculate the number of columns based on the content (thus: wrapping).

Example below:

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding-left: -16px;
  justify-content: 'center';
}

.cell {
  min-width: 20%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 8px 16px 8px 0;
}
.wide2 {
  min-width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
.wide {
  width: calc(50% - 16px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="cell wide">
    wide
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    test
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    test second line, should also have zero margin to left
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont">
  <div class="cell wide">
    wide
  </div>
  <div class="cell wide2">
    this should line up,<br> iff margin right is no longer there
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not aware of a selector for the wrapped element in flex-wrap. Wouldn't it be simpler to either apply it to the first element as well or just apply a right margin?

Comment: @uchamp of course it should also apply to the first element, what do you mean? The goal is to have only a margin *between* all elements, but zero the margins to the redline/container.

Comment: Is this what you want? cell { margin: 8px 0;

Comment: @Leo then the margins between cells also become 0. The cells the don't divide to each other anymore.

Comment: then just use .cont { justify-content: space-between;

Comment: Use a more specific margin setting on the .cell ... margin: 8px 8px 8px 0px;

Comment: @uchamp That gives the problem "on the other side": where if the divs actually "match" the width they still wrap to next line - due to "white space" that is not eaten away.

Comment: I hear you. but that'll be an issue even with margin 8px on all sides

Comment: @uchamp hence this post: is it possible to only define margins between children, is it possible to let the container eat margins or can a grid (and `grid-gap`) be used with wrapping?

Comment: @paul23 .. hope you've gotten past this. I don't think it is possible with flex-wrap, because I read somewhere that flexbox doesn't support collapsing margin. You can achieve the same thing with blocks, inline-blocks and collapsing margin though. Checkout how bootstrap handles its grids.

Comment: or try something like this, as @Leo suggested too. [Flexbox with space-between](https://jsfiddle.net/29svwcqm/)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is currently not possible, and probably won't ever be.

You see, if you can have that selector, you'll be able to implement this:

```css
.flexbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flexbox .flex-item {
    margin-left: 200px;
}
.flexbox .flex-item:first-of-flex-line {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Notice that when `margin-left: 0` of `:first-of-flex-line` cancels the `margin-left: 20px` rule, it can possibly make some items of the next line move up, almost like infinite loop. This would require iterative layouting, which seems unlikely to be implemented in browser as it is expensive rendering.